# Hosting WordPress in an EC2 load-balanced instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, wordpress

Whenever my Amazon EC2 instance is stopped or rebooted, a new instance is made with an AMI.

This normally is fine for applications that are managed with a service like [Puppet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_%28software%29), but our WordPress site is not. I have to do a manual restore/upgrade to the latest WordPress from daily backups.

Is there a way to host WordPress on an Amazon instance with some kind of persistence storage for the WordPress files?

I know about EBS volumes, but I'm not sure how to get /var/app/current to "store there".

Answer (score 6):

You should be using EFS volumes for shared storage, like the wp-content folder, and RDS for the database. EBS won't help you for this.

AWS has a good pattern available [here](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/resources/aws-refarch-wordpress/). It links to templates and such on GitHub [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-refarch-wordpress).

[image: AWS WordPress]

There's another pattern available [here](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/build-wordpress-website/) as well that gives you a full deployment guide.

**Lightsail**

AWS is great for WordPress if you need high availability or have a very high load. [AWS Lightsail makes WordPress easy](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/projects/wordpress/), though not highly available, and it can be much cheaper than EC2 especially if you use a lot of bandwidth.

Answer (score 3):

Stab in the dark here:

> Whenever my ec2 instance is stopped or rebooted, a new instance is made with an AMI.

Most likely your EC2 instance is controlled by Auto Scaling. So when the instance is stopped, Auto Scaling determines that it's "unhealthy", terminates it, then replaces it. That's why you're losing your data.

To avoid this, create a new EC2 instance that's not controlled by Auto Scaling. This way, you can start and stop it without it being replaced. The EBS volume will retain the data through the stops and restarts.

> Is there a way to host wordpress on an amazon instance with some kind of persistence storage for the wordpress files?

EBS-backed EC2 instances do provide the persistent storage you're looking for. However, I think the issue is that the act of stopping the EC2 instance is terminating and re-creating the instance.